# Set VerticalAlignment of LongListMultiSelector content

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, wptoolkit

I'm using the LongListMultiSelector of the WP Toolkit to select multiple items. I've written a DataTemplate, which is a little bit complex and have a hight of round about 140px. Now I want to change the position of the Checkbox to VerticalAlignment Top to VerticalAlignment Center. I've tried to change the style of the LongListMultiSelector, but this doesn't work.

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: Since the DataTemplate defines the Checkbox, you probably need to adjust the DataTemplate instead.

Comment: No, the CheckBox is defined by the style of the LongListMultiSelector, but I can't figure out where to change.

Answer (score 0):

It's the LongListMultiSelector's ItemContainerStyle. [Here](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.WP8/Themes/Generic.xaml) you find the toolkit's styles. Copy the < Style x:Key="LongListMultiSelectorItemListStyle" TargetType="controls:LongListMultiSelectorItem">, change the x:Key, and change the line which says < CheckBox x:Name="SelectBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" ...